# Give an example of a uniformly continuous function $f$ on $[0, 1]$ that is differentiable on $(0, 1)$ but for which $f'$ is not bounded on $(0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Any help would be appreciated! Would $f(x) = \sqrt(x)$ work?

Give an example of a uniformly continuous function $f$ on $[0, 1]$ that is differentiable on $(0, 1)$ but for which $f'$ is not bounded on $(0, 1)$

Comment: That would work, giving a vertical tangent at the origin. Or how about fitting a semicircle on the interval, so you get vertical tangents at both endpoints?

Comment: Any continuous $f:[0,1]\to R$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also take $f(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ when $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[0,1]$, differentiable in $(0,1)$ but the derivative $2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2}) - \frac{2}{x}\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})$ is unbounded.

Comment: @Brain Enjoy...

Comment: @KushalBhuyan ?